# How can I send a UILongPressGesture programmatically?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

How can I send a `UILongPressGesture` message to an object?

I know how to send touches, but not gestures. For example, if I wanted to send a touch I could use:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the button would receive a "touch up inside". I need to do the same thing with a long press gesture.

Think automated UI testing. Calling a selector associated with the gesture wouldn't meaningfully test anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "message to an object"?

Comment: @iProgrammed Please see my reworded question for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>` and manually set the `state` property as appropriate to the sequence of states you need to simulate. This will cause the added target/action pairs to be called. After each time manually setting the state, you must let the run loop run in order for the messages to be dispatched.

For the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, to get the correct sequence of states as is found in an actual, 'touch, hold, drag, release' sequence of gestures, I wrote the following code in a `UIViewController` subclass inside `viewDidLoad`.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *r = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:r];
[r addTarget:self action:@selector(recognize:)];
r.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
r.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
r.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
[r reset];
```

I imagine this would be risky in production code (you may wish afterwards to call `reset` but I found no difference between doing so or not in my testing), but if your use case is automated testing to verify that the targets and actions have been set correctly this may meet your needs.

Comment: I still have some timing issues and such to work out, but this puts me on the right track (and definitely answers the question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what selector the object has tied to its `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`? If you knew that, you could just call it. If you're asking if there's a method like `touchesMoved:(UITouch *)touch`, then the answer's no.

Comment: Like `[button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`, but with a gesture instead of a touch event. Are you saying in your second sentence that no, it's not possible?