# UIPageViewController transitioning to another view on event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, transition

I have a UIPageViewController with 3 views. I want to change from one view to another on a button event (something like snapchat buttons that help you through navigation, even though swipes also do the job). I'm currently using the following:

```
//the navWrapper is the view currently displayed
//it asks the PageViewController to set its view abruptly to the nextWrapper
[navWrapper.rootViewController.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[nextWrapper] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This works because it changes the view controller displayed correctly, but I'm looking a way to have that transition **just like a swipe would look like** (instead of the harsh change in the view with no animation that is going on right now).

Been looking around but haven't figured this out yet, suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: try to use scrollView instead of PageView if you want to animate the transition

Comment: Why are you passing NO for the animated argument if you want the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set `animated` to YES

```
[navWrapper.rootViewController.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[nextWrapper] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and if you are interested there is a way to trigger the gesture recognizer programmatically in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408455/how-can-i-send-a-uilongpressgesture-programmatically)

Comment: Holy crap, so tired and beat up those kind of stuff just slip through xD Thanks!