# UITableViewCell Sliding Simulation in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

On the first run in my app, I want to show the users that they can slide the cells in the TableView for more options.
How can I let the cell animated automatically to slide -> show the options -> then back to normal?? (Sliding Simulation) in swift..

This will inform users that there are more options on sliding the cell.

I have seen some apps does that on the first run of the app.

Thanks

Comment: can you please mention the app name with similar effect ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia app name: Qrafter ... you find the effect in history tab.

Comment: Qrafter must be using a custom view and not the built-in APIs used with `UITableViewRowAction`s.  Looking at the `UITableViewCell` header, there may be some private properties to programmatically invoke the gesture recognizer, but I haven't been able to figure this out yet.

Comment: Did you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418044/3950397?

Comment: It may helps to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766243/uitableview-invoke-swipe-actions-programmatically

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, but what I'm looking for is Swipe Simulation. To show the user that there is more option when s/he swipes the cell.

Comment: Maybe a slightly "hacky" way. But why not just create a UIView with background colour the same as your tableview cell. Add a button or what ever on the right side(options like you mentioned). Make the width X wider(width of options btn) then your tableView frame width. Height same as tableview cell. Position it over your table view cell, but slightly off screen to the right(to hide options btn). On load, animate in to view. Then animate away(back to right) and remove from view.

Comment: I think that the best approach is to use a [coach mark](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-instructional-overlay/) a transparent overlay of UI hints used in many application to instruct the user on how to use use the app.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution to only show it the first time, I would use Core Data to save a bool. Open the app the first time -> animate -> save to core data that the animation played. Next time the app loads fetch that bool and skip the animation

Comment: Does your `UITableViewCell` have a `UIScrollView` inside or are you *faking*  the scrolling with a `UISwipeGestureRecogniser`? If you actually have a scroll view, simply change the scroll offset and animate it back.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000276/7235585

Answer (score 0):

sounds like what you trying to do is a UISwipeGestureRecgoniser

example of this would be as follows , maybe its something you can implement :-

```
func handleMySwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecogniser) {

if sender.direction == .Down {

println("you swiped down")

 }

 if sender.direction == .Right {

println("you swiped right")

  }

 if sender.direction == .Up {

 println("you swiped up")

 }

 if sender.direction == .Left {

 println("you swiped down")

     }   


   override func viewDidLoad() {

   //swipe from left for example

   swipeRecogniser.direction = .Left

    }



  //then add it to your view

  view.addGestureRecogniser(swipeRecogniser)

   }
```